# Run command before popping up file selection with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

I have a simple question, or maybe not. Is there an pre-click-event before the file selection popping up after clicking the file upload button? I want to check if the user is logged in, if he's not logged in, the file selection popupbox should not appear, but a message with a note, that the user must be logged in to upload something.
I'm using JS with jQuery.

Comment: Could be onfocus, onmousedown. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a `onclick` event on this button.

For example:

```
onclick="alert('!');"
```

the actions will be:

`[click]` upload button -> `[alert]` -> `[click]` confirm button -> `[popup]` the file selector.

============= update ===============================================================

in HTML

```
<input id="FileBtn" onclick="AuthCheck()">
```

in js scope

```
var AuthCheck = function(){
    if(AuthFail){
        document.getElementById("FileBtn").disabled=true;
        setTimeout('document.getElementById("FileBtn").disabled=false;', 1);
    }
}
```

it works on Chrome ver.29

Comment: I forgot to say, that i want to check if the user is not logged in, it should unload the popup. So if you are logged in, you can easily upload something, but if you are not logged in, it should only appear a messagebox with note, that you should be logged in. You know what i mean?